# Facebook Media ID to URL

Tags: algorithm, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I am looking to convert a media object ID given by Facebook's Graph API to a useable URL. This was a [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609420/find-instagram-media-url-by-id) problem, but Facebook seems to have changed the algorithm they use to convert IDs to short links.

Under the old algorithm an ID of `17932660891440268` would convert to a URL of `/p/_taj6T9SM/`. Now though, the same ID becomes `/p/CIHBkEnpKPl/`. Does anyone know the algorithm to make that conversation?

Comment: Doesn't the API have a way to get the URL?

Comment: I would like to do it with an extra an API call if possible. And my current app does not have permission to use that endpoint.